# Sharing variables between objects of different classes (C++)

Tags: c++, class, variables, share

I feel like I should already know how to do this but I'm not really sure of the best way to do it.

I have class A with a private class B object and class C object in it, and in the class C object, I need to access members of the class B object and the parent class A object, is there an easy way to do that?

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_classes_objects.htm plus other Google spewed results...

Comment: Why is it that you have to go about the structure this way?

Answer (score 0):

In  class C, you may have members that are pointers to Class B and class A objects. But anyway there is no straight way to access private variables of an object from outside.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to 'inject' these dependencies by passing a reference for class A (through which you can access class B anyway) to class C, either via the constructor of class C or some method that you define.

In class C you can define the type of the reference (ie a pointer) and then assign it the value from the input of the constructor or the method (depending on what option you choose).

EDIT: @Nipun is correct, if object B is private then u can't access it from outside of itself anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really the place for me to say this, but if I find myself in a situation like this it generally means that I have designed my classes messily and they need adjusting or a complete redesign...